# Iterated Self-composition of Linear Mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am working on a Linear Algebra exercise as follow:

> Prove that $F^2$ is invertible if $F: W \rightarrow W$ is linear mapping and also  $F^2 + F^5 - F^3 + I = 0.$

Here I was hinted that I need to find an inverse of $F^2$ such that the composition of both of them is $I.$ And I also believe that the solution may involve the high school algebra formula that is $(1 - x^n) = (1-x)(1+x+x^2+ \ldots +x^n).$ I have been trying to find the inverse but I could not find any. Here is my question then: Is there any property of the iterated composition of mapping of itself that I should be aware of to solve this problem? Or, do you have any other suggestion if there isn't any?

Keep in mind that I am still in the early months of this semester in Linear Algebra, so I haven't had any high-end theorems yet at my disposal. Any help or hint would be very much appreciated. Thank you before hand for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

$$F^2+F^5-F^3+I=0$$

then

$$F^2(-I-F^3+F)=I$$

and

$$(-I-F^3+F)F^2=I.$$

So $F^2$ is invertible with inverse $-I-F^3+F$.

Comment: Wow! Thank you and thank you again!